# Xcode7 swift function needs to much time? Race condition?

Tags: facebook, swift, xcode7

i have a problem in my Xcode 7 Project, regarding Facebook.
When trying to retrieve my data, with a graph request, the function returnUserData finishes too late?

```
//...
returnUserData()
print("finished")
//...
```

And this is the function:

```
func returnUserData() {
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email"])
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil
            {
                //print("fetched user: \(result)")
                print("start");
                self.username = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
                //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.username, forKey: "name")
                //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                print("1: " + (self.username as String))
            }
        else if (error != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        })

    }
```

But this is, what happens, look at the order:

```
finished
start
1: My Name
```

How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler` call is asynchronous. If you place breakpoints in your code at `returnUserData()` and `print("finished")`, you will see that after `graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler` is executed, the function will immediately return to `print("finished")` statement and the statements within the completion handler are not executed (immediately after `graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler` call).

In order to handle it properly, either you write your processing code [for ex: `print("finished")`] within the completionHandler or write a callback function to which you can pass the data after processing/ validating the server response.

Comment: That was too easy and it works. Just put the code into the completionHandler.

Comment: Glad that helped. Its better to understand how asynchronous call work, so I suggest you read up further [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know, how it works, but don't know, why i didn't think of that solution. Strange thing is, that also semaphores did not work. The asynchronous function was never sending the signal.

Comment: [This](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87016/swift-ios-call-back-functions) could provide you more info.  If my answer has helped you, you can mark it answered.